# Calculated field in Tableau using a running count and windowing

Tags: visualization, tableau-desktop

I was wondering if i counld have a calculated field that count the number of races a driver has particapated in, i have a table called `results.csv` it contains a `raceid` and `driveridv these should help identify everything:

I want the new calculated field to return something like this:

RaceId, DriverId, calculated field

18, 2, 1

18, 3, 1

19, 2, 2

19, 3, 2

19, 4, 1

Any help would be deeply appreciated,
have a nice day

I tried using WINDOW_COUNT and RUNNING_TOTAL, but i'm not sure my syntax was right

Answer (score 1):

The simple table calc
INDEX()

Will give you running count, be sure to
Compute using RaceId